# Network render outputs pink frames

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, network

My setup is a Windows 10 system running one client and one master, and two Linux Mint systems running as slaves. Four GPUs per slave.

As far as the network setup goes, everything seems normal. The clients are able to communicate with each other, anyway. Problem is, when I click Animation on Network in the client, the render viewport starts empty. Then, once the 'results' start coming back, the frames are pink, and look more like what you would see when using the viewport during mesh construction. There should be an image background in the world, but that isn't visible either.

I've made sure that cycles is selected in the client configuration, and all the render settings such as sampling were configured in the cycles mode before switching to the network render mode.

I've tested this with both animation, and with a simple single frame render. Same results. Everything renders fine under cycles without the network render.

What am I missing? And is there any other information I should provide?

EDIT: I've noticed some other questions here getting answers about seeing pink when there are missing textures. I suppose I should point out that everything in my scene is currently just materials. The only image used is for the world.

Comment: No textures are being used

Comment: You just said yourself you use an image for the world. How are you not using textures?

Comment: The world, yes. Everything else is just material. There should not be any of that kind of pink issue outlined in other questions when I'm rendering internal shots where the world is not visible. So finding missing files will not  work, because there is no file to find in the first place.

Comment: If the world texture is not refrenced properly the whole scene is lit in pink, too. How does that not have an impact. Have you tried disabling the texture? Have you tried packing the textures under 'file->external data->' before sending it to the farm?

Comment: I'll have to give that a try later tonight when I get home. Will let you know.

Comment: No change. Tried completely removing the texture from the nodes and using a solid blue background node. Still pink. Tried packing. No difference.